# Sound interruption in bluetooth headphones

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth, 22.04, headphones

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I have some problems with sound in my bluetooth headphones(MAJOR IV). When I play any videos in the browser I have intermittent audio interruptions.I changed my browser, but It didn't help. I changed audio profile from A2DP Sink to HFP and the sound stopped intermittent, but the quality of sound became very bad. I tried to disable the bluetooth continuously scan devices by commands "bluetoothctl" and then "scan off", but I got an error: org.bluez.Error.Failed. So my problem is still unresolved :(
I hope you will help me!
Thanks for your attention!

P.S. It is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    DeviceName: Intel Stone Peak 2  7265 Combo /NON-vPro NGFF Combo Wireless-AC 7265
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 2.4 GHz W-Fi shares the same band as Bluetooth.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

The setting can be reverted by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

But a really good solution is to use 5 GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: Pilot6, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately It didn't work for me(