# Sound cracking/interruptions in bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am using bluetooth headphones with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When I'm listening to music or watching a video, I have sound intermittent sound interruptions. I have tried:

[A2DP on PulseAudio - terrible choppy/skipping audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio) and [Sound interruption in bluetooth headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415951/sound-interruption-in-bluetooth-headphones) this  articles to solve my problem, but they didn't help me...

So, I hope you will help me!

Output of : `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04ca:00ac Lite-On Technology Corp. Dell Wireless Device
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 048d:8297 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8297 RGB LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.